# Open file at given descriptor

Tags: linux, file, file-descriptor

In Linux, is it possible to open a file at given file descriptor?

`man open` says:

> The open() function shall return a file descriptor for the named file that is the lowest file descriptor not currently open for that process.

Currently I'm calling `open` followed by `dup2` and `close`. 3 syscalls. Is this the best we can do?

Comment: What `dup2` is doing is creating a new file descriptor which points to original one, which is not "open a file at given file descriptor". What is the actual problem are you facing ?

Comment: @ymonad A shorter way of doing this: `fd1 = open(...); dup2(fd1, fd2); close(fd1);`

Comment: Oh, I got it. sorry for my poor english.